# Examples of continuous maps of the Cantor set onto $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Give examples of continuous maps of the Cantor set onto $\mathbb{R}$, $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$, or prove why such functions don't exist. Also prove that the Cantor function is a continuous map onto $[0,1]$.

I was thinking of using the Intermediate Value Theorem to solve this problem, but can't seem to come up with solid examples to back up my intuition.

Comment: Such functions onto $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0, 1)$ don't exist, since Cantor set is compact. Are you sure the question is correctly stated?

Comment: How did you define the cantor set?

Comment: You're correct: I missed the part where it said or prove why such functions won't exist.

Comment: A set $S_n$ consisting of $2^n$ closed intervals of length $(1/3)^n$.

Comment: @Adayah I suggest that you post the first sentence of your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I can see that your suggestion is older than skyking's answer, but now that he posted it, I'm fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

The image can't be $\mathbb R$ or $(0,1)$ since the cantor set is compact and the image of a compact set must be compact for the function to be continuous.

A map from the Cantor set to $[0,1]$ however can be found. Recall that the Cantor set is the set of numbers that can be written as $(0.xxx)_{(3)}$ where the fractional part only consists of $0$s and $2$s, also note that this expansion is unique (since ending in only $2$s would be aliased with a $1$ followed by $0$s which is not allowed). Now the mapping that replaces $2$s with $1$ and the base with $2$ would map the Cantor set to $[0,1]$, also it's quite straight forward to show that this is a continuous map in the relative topology.